# using GWT RPC mechanism with my customized Servlet

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, asynchronous, gwt-rpc

I currently have a GWT application which uses the `RequestBuilde` to 
send messages to a servlet I have (using `POST` and `GET`), and my servlet 
(in `doPost` and `doGet`) "pauses" the request (this is done by using 
Servlets 3.0 spec) and adds it to a queue.
Additionally I have a 
Daemon thread which runs in the background and "plays" the request 
when there is new data. 
This works great for me apart from the fact that I'm just sending 
strings for now and I'd like to utilize the RPC mechanism to send 
Objects.
 
My question is this:
 If I create my `myServiceImpl` class which extends 
`RemoteServiceServlet` how should I handle the `doPost` and `doGet` if at all?
 I need to pause my request to utilize the asynchronous support, where should this be accomplished? I though maybe to call `this.getThreadLocalRequest()` method in my RPC method in `myServiceImpl` class but I'm not sure how wise that will be.
 I'm not 
sure I even understand how GWT handles the call from the client side 
of that asynchronous interface. 
Does it by any chance call the `doGet` for example of the servlet and 
makes sure it calls the required RPC method? 
I'm sorry if I made a mess of things it's just that I can't find more 
detailed technical information as exactly how this RPC business works. 
Appreciate any lending hand 
Ittai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main misunderstanding I had at the time was related to the fact that GWT RPC builds on the servlet mechanism (internally) and so trying to use that mechanism with asynchronous servlets was, at the time, impossible since GWT RPC was built on servlets 2.5 (again, at the time).

Answer (score 5):

To understand RPC forget about POST and GET it works differently (that is from a programming perspective. Internally it does use it, but you don't see or need to understand it, unless you want to do something exotic). A good starting point is on RPC is the GWT docs: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/RPC.html

To give you a summary. When using RPC your servlet `myServiceImpl` needs to implement the methods of an interface named `myService`, besides extending the `RemoveServiceServlet`. The methods get as arguments the data you want to send to the server.

Next to the `myService` interface you need to create an `myServiceAsync` interface (both interface's should be in a client subpackage). This `myServiceAsync` inteface should contain the same methods as the `myService` interface except each method returns `void` and has an additional last argument `AsyncCallback callback`.

In you client you need to instrument GWT to generate the RPC via GWT.create (see the documentation for the details.

To use RPC, call the methods on the `myServiceAsync` interface in your client code and GWT takes care of sending it to the servlet. The servlet will then call the matching method with the arguments you passed on the client. This is done asynchronous. Thus the client return directly from the call.

When the server sends the result back the callback you passed `myServiceAsync` is used or `OnError` or `OnSuccess` is called. `OnError` if the method on the server side threw an error, else `OnSuccess`. The `OnSuccess` will have as argument the return value from what you returned in the method implemented by your servlet.