# Gwt RPC and Servlet

Tags: gwt, servlets

RPC is used to call any service of the server and same is the case with Servlet (calling any service of the server). so whats the differnce between the two. when do we use RPC and when Servlets. and if theres any difference. what are the advantages of the two.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service of the server ???
I think you mean to say Code on the server.

Servlet actually is itself on server.

To understand GWT RPC and Servlet programming may be you like to see :
[using GWT RPC mechanism with my customized Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425525/using-gwt-rpc-mechanism-with-my-customized-servlet/1551067#1551067)
GWT allows you to do all the server interaction without forcing you to learn any extra technology like Servlet, all you need is plain core java and you will be good to go.